# Javascript remove every other array in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have an array of arrays in which I am trying to get rid of March and September. I have been trying the below code but I am not getting any output. Please suggest what I am missing and how I can improve this.

```
//w is the data array    
for(var i = 0; i < w.length; i+=1)
       w.splice(i, 1);

 data: 
   [ [ '1983-03-31', 29.4, 29.6, 29.25, 29.29],
     [ '1983-06-30', 31.25, 31.4, 31.25, 31.38],
     [ '1983-09-30', 30.53, 30.55, 30.2, 30.36],
     [ '1983-12-31', 29.66, 29.8, 29.36, 29.6],
     [ '1984-03-31', 30.83, 30.85, 30.74, 30.85]]
```

Comment: Please add more details about the data before the operation is ran

Comment: Have you tried [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `filter`

```js
var data =   [ [ '1983-03-31', 29.4, 29.6, 29.25, 29.29],     [ '1983-06-30', 31.25, 31.4, 31.25, 31.38],     [ '1983-09-30', 30.53, 30.55, 30.2, 30.36],     [ '1983-12-31', 29.66, 29.8, 29.36, 29.6],     [ '1984-03-31', 30.83, 30.85, 30.74, 30.85]];
     
var result = data.filter(([date]) => {
  var [_, month] = date.split('-');
  return month !== '09' && month !== '03';
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Or you can follow the `slice` approach**

```js
var data =   [ [ '1983-03-31', 29.4, 29.6, 29.25, 29.29],     [ '1983-06-30', 31.25, 31.4, 31.25, 31.38],     [ '1983-09-30', 30.53, 30.55, 30.2, 30.36],     [ '1983-12-31', 29.66, 29.8, 29.36, 29.6],     [ '1984-03-31', 30.83, 30.85, 30.74, 30.85]];
     
     
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var [date] = data[i];
  var [_, month] = date.split('-');
  if (month === '09' || month === '03') {
    data = data.slice(0, i).concat(data.slice(i + 1, data.length));
  }
}

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @smac89 yes, but I didn't want to parse that date.

Comment: @Ele thank you! I am getting an error when I use your filter, 'w.filter is not a function'. I have a variable w that does JSON.parse which I use in your example.

Comment: @PopyAziz are you sure w is an array? can you print that to be sure?

Comment: @Ele Yes. I did console.log(w) and this is the output: data: 
      [ [Array],
        [Array],
        [Array],
        [Array],
        [Array]

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ele's answer that `filter` is the way to do it, and here in an alternative: if you already know that the array always comes with March first, then June, then September, then December, etc., then you can use the index of the element inside the array to determine if you want to keep the element or not. This answers the question "remove every other element" rather than the requirement of your question body of "remove March and September".

```js
var data =   [ [ '1983-03-31', 29.4, 29.6, 29.25, 29.29],     [ '1983-06-30', 31.25, 31.4, 31.25, 31.38],     [ '1983-09-30', 30.53, 30.55, 30.2, 30.36],     [ '1983-12-31', 29.66, 29.8, 29.36, 29.6],     [ '1984-03-31', 30.83, 30.85, 30.74, 30.85]];
     
var result = data.filter((_, i) => {
  return i % 2 == 1;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use `.filter()`, `.every()` and `.includes()`:

```js
let monthsToFilter = ['03', '09'];
let data = [
    ['1983-03-31', 29.4, 29.6, 29.25, 29.29],
    ['1983-06-30', 31.25, 31.4, 31.25, 31.38],
    ['1983-09-30', 30.53, 30.55, 30.2, 30.36],
    ['1983-12-31', 29.66, 29.8, 29.36, 29.6],
    ['1984-03-31', 30.83, 30.85, 30.74, 30.85]
];
     
let result = data.filter(([date]) => {
    return monthsToFilter.every(m => !date.includes('-' + m + '-'));
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Useful Resources:**

- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)
- [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)